# Best way to use Bootstrap with React? Directly or with a library?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

What is the standard way to apply Bootstrap (or Bootstrap-like) styling to a React web app?

Is the preferred way to do it directly, or does the community tend to use a library?

If it's a library, which library is most popular? I know this is subjective, and I find that in general there is consensus around one or a small number. If there are a few that are generally accepted, what are the trade-offs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arguably the most popular library when working with React and Bootstrap is [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/). This gives you convenient components to use which already have all the classes etc.

It is worth noting, however:

> Because React-Bootstrap doesn't depend on a very precise version of Bootstrap, we don't ship with any included CSS. However, some stylesheet is required to use these components. How and which bootstrap styles you include is up to you, but the simplest way is to include the latest styles from the CDN.

Most implementations I've seen leverage use of build tools like Webpack and use loaders such as the [sass-loader](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader). This will allow you to use the official [Bootstrap sass library](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#d-npm--nodejs).

If your needs are not so complex, you always have the option to just include the CSS in your initial `index.html`.

As with most things in front-end development: there is no absolute right answer.

Answer (score 1):

To build off the previous answer, the [Google Material library](http://www.material-ui.com/#/) features more components than React Bootstrap and allows for easy customization.

Material is available as a npm package.

Answer (score 0):

[React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) is currently in Beta for Bootstrap v4. With that in mind I'd recommend waiting before using it in production apps (unless you're happy to use Bootstrap v3).

If your app is using a webpacker/compiler, then it is best to install bootstrap as a dependency using `npm install bootstrap`. If not, then you can install using a cdn (include the link element in your index.html file).